# Low WiFi speeds on 75Mbps WiFi Router / Macbook Air / Mac OS Mojave

Tags: wireless-networking, macos-mojave, internet-speed, macbook-air

The situation: I have 75 Mbit/s at home, everything’s fine on mobile wifi, but on the MacBook Air everything is very sad: all of a sudden for no reason, literally 1 Mbit/s. Symptoms: I start the SpeedTest - it starts at 10, immediately goes down to 1 mbps and even lower.

It’s not related to browsers since I installed the SpeedTest application separately, it’s the same there.

What I tried:

- disabled the built-in firewall. No effect
- flush dns, No effect
- deleted configuration files 1. com.apple.airport.preferences.plist 2. com.apple.network.eapolclient.configuration.plist 3. NetworkInterfaces.plist 4. preferences.plist - rebooted. No effect
- the router rebooted a million times, but this is clearly not it, because everything is fine on the mobile

What else to reset/check I'm rocking my brain. NVRAM / PRAM?

Comment: Язык этого сайта StackExchange - английский. Пожалуйста, оставьте свой вопрос на английском или с английским переводом, если вы хотите получить помощь здесь.  The language of this StackExchange site is English. Please post your question in English, or with an English translation, if you wish to receive assistance here.

Comment: Try the speed test at [DSLReports](http://www.dslreports.com/speedtest) which has an extra test for bufferbloat - which is what I suspect might be your issue.

Comment: Tried it, but don't see how can be a bloat on a Mac but not on Mobile. The router is the same

Answer (score 0):

After extensive searching found a way that fixed the problem:

created a new user, logged in, checked speed from there: the connection was working 100% fast. Loaded the old profile back — magic, the same result. Judging from some other answers, could be a hindering piece of software or who knows what... I didn't uninstall anything and I don't run any VPN services. So still a mystery, how it worked out.